# Fetch headers in ReactJs when redirected from NodeJs with some headers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Suppose I want to redirect to another application using nodejs and I have added headers while redirecting.
How I can get the headers in reactjs application on loading.

I am able to redirect successfuly and able to see the header present in the Network tab. But don't know how to get it programmatically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider someone is sending a request with a token to my backend and I am verifying that token and redirecting it my frontend URL. But now I want some information to be passed to that URL. But I don't want to send that information as URL parameter. How I can send that information?